# Функция CryptoAPI

Tags: c++, c++builder

Здравствуйте. Пишу программу по защите информации в рамках лабораторной работы, в которой есть следующее задание:

> Зашифровать файл с учетными записями при помощи функций `CryptoAPI` с использованием сеансового ключа. Используемый алгоритм хеширования - `MD5`.

Расскажите, подскажите, как вообще работать с `CryptoAPI` в C++ Builder. Как зашифровывать файлы с помощью `MD5` и что такое **потоковый тип симметричного шифрования**?

Comment: MD5 - не шифрование, а хэширование.

Answer (score 1):

Справка по теме: [использование Crypto API](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/crypto/usingcryptoapi.xml). В разделе шифрование статьи приведены примеры вызова функций CryptEncryptMessage и CryptDecryptMessage. В C++ Builder работать с этими функциями можно также, как и с любыми другими функциями Windows API.

Симметричные алгоритмы используют один и тот же секретный ключ для зашифровки и расшифровки. В потоковых разновидностях единицей кодирования является один бит. А на результат операции кодирования не влияет уже прошедший поток. Нужно в тех случаях, когда операция шифрования может случайно обрываться.

Comment: IMHO, лучше CryptEncrypt - просто шифрование данных.